# How to group rows with same values in sql and don't disturb after applying order by?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, row

How to group rows with same values in sql and can't disturb after applying order by.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
  id int NOT NULL,
  title varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  description varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  price int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO products VALUES
  (1, 'test', 'test',2222),
  (2, 'test', 'test2',1111),
  (3, 'test3', 'test3',1111),
  (4, 'test3.2', 'test3.2',555),
  (5, 'test3.3', 'test3.3',1111),
  (6, 'test4', 'test4 desc',1111);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  tempId,pemId, 
  
  title,
  
  description,
  (CASE priceno WHEN 1 THEN price ELSE price END )AS price
  
FROM
(                   
    SELECT 
        
        
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY price) AS priceno,
        tempId,pemId,title,description,price
    FROM (
            select id as tempId,id as pemId,title,description,price from products
                group by 
                    
                    grouping sets((tempId,price),(tempId,pemId,title,description))
                
         ) As b
) As s
order by
    
    tempId, price asc;
```

| tempid | pemid | title | description | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  | 2222 |
| 1 | 1 | test | test |  |
| 2 |  |  |  | 1111 |
| 2 | 2 | test | test2 |  |
| 3 |  |  |  | 1111 |
| 3 | 3 | test3 | test3 |  |
| 4 |  |  |  | 555 |
| 4 | 4 | test3.2 | test3.2 |  |
| 5 |  |  |  | 1111 |
| 5 | 5 | test3.3 | test3.3 |  |
| 6 |  |  |  | 1111 |
| 6 | 6 | test4 | test4 desc |  |

---

**Expected Output:**
[image]

Please suggest any solution in sql. Thank you!

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uw2DM2zQaYKwNPTqdT2FUc/27)

Comment: Can you explain the rationale behind your output in details? @MuhammadUsman

Comment: @lemon I want to display data in MUI DataGridPro table like it's own grouping feature but using sql not their feature. you can check here: [mui-row-grouping](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-grouping/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
  id int NOT NULL,
  title varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  description varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  price int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO products VALUES
  (1, 'test', 'test',2222),
  (2, 'test', 'test2',1111),
  (3, 'test3', 'test3',1111),
  (4, 'test3.2', 'test3.2',555),
  (5, 'test3.3', 'test3.3',1111),
  (6, 'test4', 'test4 desc',1111);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select id, 
title, 
description,
(CASE WHEN prno=1 THEN price::varchar ELSE '' END )AS price
from(
  select DISTINCT id, title, description, price, prno
from (
  select id, 1, null, null, null, price::varchar, 1 as prno from products
  union all
  select id, 2, id::varchar, title, description, price::varchar, 2 as prno from products
) temp1 (xid, xord, id, title, description,price,prno)
 order by price, prno
) as temp2;
```

| id | title | description | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | 1111 |
| 2 | test | test2 |  |
| 6 | test4 | test4 desc |  |
| 3 | test3 | test3 |  |
| 5 | test3.3 | test3.3 |  |
|  |  |  | 2222 |
| 1 | test | test |  |
|  |  |  | 555 |
| 4 | test3.2 | test3.2 |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ncF9Vwd4JMZ7WKa7XrDdC/0)